# Where does the phrase a "lick of" something come from?

Tags: phrases

The phrase a "lick of" something means a small quantity of something.

What I want to know is where does this phrase come from?

Comment: -1 Please add your own attempts to research and anything you found out. Close General Reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from the longer phrase ***a lick and a promise***.  From the OED:

> b. colloq. A slight and hasty wash (usually **a lick and a promise**). Also, a dab of paint, etc.; a hasty tidying up, a casual amount of work.
>
> - C. 1648 in Maidment Pasquils (1868) 154 ― We’ll mark them with a lick of tarre.
> - A. 1771 Gray Candidate 2 ― When sly Jemmy Twitcher had smugg’d up his face With a lick of court white-wash, and pious grimace.
> - 1855 Robinson Whitby Gloss., ― A Lick and a Slake.
> - 1860 W. White All round the Wrekin xx. 207 ― We only gives the cheap ones a lick and a promise.
> - 1899 E. F. Heddle Marget at Manse 43 ― That lassie gi’es a lick and a promise when I tell her to sweep!
> - 1922 A. Bennett Lilian i. vi. 57 ― The dirty kitchenmaid was giving the stone floor of the porch a lick and a promise.
> - 1934 L. A. G. Strong Corporal Tune iii. ii. 230 ― The room, instead of its usual vigorous cleaning, got what Nelly would have called a lick and a promise.
> - 1942 C. Morley Thorofare xl. 355 ― You ought to be writing the Adventures of a Crustacean. You’ve only done a lick and a promise. There’s six more inches to fill.
> - 1948 M. McCarthy in Partisan Rev. May-June 325 ― The Dublin Gate players··had a slapdash style of acting that suggested an Irish house‐maid flailing about with a dust-cloth-they gave their roles a lick and a promise and trusted to the audience’s good-nature to take the will for the deed.
> - 1967 V. Lincoln Private Disgrace (1968) xi. 91 ― She had only a basin of water and a rag with which to give the insides of the windows a lick and a promise.
> - 1969 D. Clark Death after Evensong vi. 142 ― A pale sun gave Rooksby a lick and a promise of better things to come.
> - 1972 J. Burmeister Running Scared iii. 51 ― The isolation ward··was given a lick and a promise once a month by an unsupervised maid.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the archetypal "lick" is [a lick of paint](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20lick%20of%20paint&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Which was definitely around in 1827...

> [A lick of paint would improve this.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22my%20point%20is%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20lick%20of%20paint%20would%22&oq=%22a%20lick%20of%20paint%20would%22&gs_l=serp.3...18353.19680.0.20137.6.6.0.0.0.0.54.280.6.6.0...0.0...1c.NaxbmpYjtVs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=697ea793e1b56b93&biw=1379&bih=886)

Against **lick**, OED gives *colloq. A slight and hasty wash (usually a lick and a promise). Also, a dab of paint, etc.; a hasty tidying up, **a casual amount of work**.*